# Ideas for why PATH has these directories

Tags: bash, arch-linux, zsh, path

In my .profile I have `PATH="$HOME/.local/lib:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.node_modules/bin:$HOME/.cargo/bin:$HOME/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"`
In my .zshrc I have miniconda path stuff (export PATH="/home/user/miniconda3/bin:$PATH") but I removed that and it seems its the last that gets loaded and so I don't think thats the issue.
However, in my shell, I get the following

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cuda/bin:/opt/cuda/nsight_compute:/opt/cuda/nsight_systems/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

Maybe some arch packages set these paths? But what's setting sbin in my path? I'm not root.

Also my PATH command from .profile is not being picked up, I've tried it with and without export. I'm pretty sure it used to work. (EDIT: seems zsh only sources .zprofile)

Comment: a `lib` directory almost certainly should not be part of your `$PATH`. Also, you really shouldn't have to add `/usr/bin`: On arch, [`/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` are all symbolic links to `/usr/bin`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Frequently_asked_questions#Does_Arch_follow_the_Linux_Foundation's_Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard_(FHS)?) So, that's already in that list – a couple of times now.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I added them because when installing some packages in arch some binaries in those directories were not being found. I've commented out PATH in .profile but my shell $PATH is still the same value. How can I find out what's modifying PATH?

Comment: I've been known for applying grep, ag or ripgrep against the whole of /etc, but especially /etc/profile.d

Answer (score 2):

The strange thing is the `lib` directory. Having `sbin` is normal since, for the past few years, more and more Linux distributions have been making `sbin` dirs symlnks to their corresponding `bin` dirs. For example, on my Arch:

```
$ ls -ld /sbin /usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jan 31 20:51 /sbin -> usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Jan 31 20:51 /usr/sbin -> bin
```

And this is explained in the [Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Frequently_asked_questions#Does_Arch_follow_the_Linux_Foundation%27s_Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard_(FHS)?):

> Arch Linux follows the file system hierarchy for operating systems using the [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd) service manager. See [file-hierarchy(7)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/file-hierarchy.7) for an explanation of each directory along with their designations. In particular, `/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` are symbolic links to `/usr/bin`, and `/lib` and `/lib64` are symbolic links to `/usr/lib`.

This, the merging of the `bin` and `sbin` directories by making `sbin`s symlinks to the corresponding `bin`s is becoming more and more common. The folks at freedesktop.org make the case for it [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), and I am reproducing some of their main arguments below:

> **Compatibility: The Gist of It**
>
> - Improved compatibility with other Unixes/Linuxes in behavior: After the `/usr` merge all binaries become available in both `/bin` and
>   `/usr/bin`, resp. both `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` (simply because `/bin`
>   becomes a symlink to `/usr/bin`, resp. `/sbin` to `/usr/sbin`). That
>   means scripts/programs written for other Unixes or other Linuxes and
>   ported to your distribution will no longer need fixing for the file
>   system paths of the binaries called, which is otherwise a major source
>   of frustration. `/usr/bin` and `/bin` (resp. `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin`)
>   become entirely equivalent.
> - Improved compatibility with other Unixes (in particular Solaris) in appearance: The primary commercial Unix implementation is nowadays
>   Oracle Solaris. Solaris has already completed the same `/usr` merge in
>   Solaris 11. By making the same change in Linux we minimize the
>   difference towards the primary Unix implementation, thus easing
>   portability from Solaris.
> - Improved compatibility with GNU build systems: The biggest part of Linux software is built with GNU autoconf/automake (i.e. GNU
>   autotools), which are unaware of the Linux-specific `/usr` split.
>   Maintaining the `/usr` split requires non-trivial project-specific
>   handling in the upstream build system, and in your distribution's
>   packages. With the `/usr` merge, this work becomes unnecessary and
>   porting packages to Linux becomes simpler.
> - Improved compatibility with current upstream development: In order to minimize the delta from your Linux distribution to upstream
>   development the `/usr` merge is key.
>
> [. . .]
>
> **Beyond Compatibility**
>
> One major benefit of the /usr merge is the reduction of complexity of
> our system: the new file system hierarchy becomes much simpler, and
> the separation between (read-only, potentially even immutable)
> vendor-supplied OS resources and users resources becomes much cleaner.
> As a result of the reduced complexity of the hierarchy, packaging
> becomes much simpler too, since the problems of handling the split in
> the .spec files go away.
>
> The merged directory /usr, containing almost the entire
> vendor-supplied operating system resources, offers us a number of new
> features regarding OS snapshotting and options for enterprise
> environments for network sharing or running multiple guests on one
> host. Static vendor-supplied OS resources are monopolized at a single
> location, that can be made read-only easily, either for the whole
> system or individually for each service. Most of this is much harder
> to accomplish, or even impossible, with the current arbitrary split of
> tools across multiple directories.
>
> With all vendor-supplied OS resources in a single directory /usr they
> may be shared atomically, snapshots of them become atomic, and the
> file system may be made read-only as a single unit.

As for what is setting them in your `PATH`, in the case of `/usr/local/sbin`, that is added by the default `/etc/profile` file:

```
$ grep sbin /etc/profile
append_path '/usr/local/sbin'
```

I can't find where `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` are added though, which is odd. They don't seem to be mentioned in any of the files I can think of that could be setting them. I created a new user, `bib2` on my system, and that user has the following PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

However, apart from `/usr/local/sbin`, the other `sbin` dirs aren't mentioned in the obvious places:

```
$ grep -HR sbin ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile \
       ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
        /etc/profile.d/ /etc/environment /etc/security/pam_env.conf \
        /etc/login.defs 2>/dev/null 
/etc/profile:append_path '/usr/local/sbin'
/etc/login.defs:ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
/etc/login.defs:ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
/etc/login.defs:#USERDEL_CMD    /usr/sbin/userdel_local
```

So these must be defined somewhere else, but I can't find where.

Comment: Cool thanks for the findings, learned a something new today :). It's kind of interesting to note that the order of your sbin vs bin is different. For example, when I run which python it shows /sbin/python which can be a bit more confusing that /bin/python. Hopefully, it will get clearer in the future.